# Ruby on Rails relationship between r models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

So I'm trying to create a relationship between 3 models. Items, Categories & Transactions.

Each Item belongs to one Category and Categories can have several Items.

```
Class User

end

Class Item
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :transactions
end

Class Category
    has_many :items
end

Class Categorization
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :category
end

Class Transactions
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :items
end
```

Where I am running into issues is that I want for Users to be able to create Items without them being tied to a Transaction. Currently when I run Rspec I'm getting error "Expected Transaction to have a has_many association called items (Item does not have a transaction_id foreign key). Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say, in the Transactions class (this should probably be Transaction (singlular), is that just a typo?)

```
has_many :items
```

rails expects the items table to have a transaction id, and to belongs_to :items

You have

```
has_many :transactions
```

in items, which suggests that they have a "has and belongs to many" relationship.  If this is the case then you should make a join table/model which links items and transactions together.  Similarly, your relationships between items and categories look similarly confused.  Are they meant to have a "has and belongs to many" relationship too?  I think that you might want it set up like this:

```
Class Item
  has_many :item_transactions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :transactions, :through => :item_transactions
  has_many :categorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end

class ItemTransaction
  #has fields item_id, transaction_id
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :transaction
end

Class Category
  has_many :categorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :items, :through => :categorizations
end

Class Categorization
  #has fields item_id, category_id
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :category
end

Class Transaction
  #has field user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :item_transactions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :items, :through => :item_transactions
end
```

Comment: I had an `itemtransaction table` setup previously but for it didn't have the relationships setup correctly. Thanks a lot Rspec now passes.